# Get list of all sequences and its values in Firebird SQL

Tags: sql, firebird

I need a list of all existing sequences and its value. I have tried:

```
SELECT RDB$GENERATOR_NAME, GEN_ID(RDB$GENERATOR_NAME, 0) FROM RDB$GENERATORS;
```

or

```
SELECT G.RDB$GENERATOR_NAME, GEN_ID(G.RDB$GENERATOR_NAME, 0) FROM RDB$GENERATORS G;
```

but these are not correct because `GEN_ID()` treats the first argument as a very generator name, i.e. tries to access to the generator `G.RDB$GENERATOR_NAME` instead of the value of `G.RDB$GENERATOR_NAME`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
execute block
returns (
    out_name char(31),
    out_value bigint)
as
begin
    for select rdb$generator_name from rdb$generators where rdb$system_flag is distinct from 1 into out_name do
    begin
        execute statement 'select gen_id(' || out_name || ', 0) from rdb$database' into out_value;
        suspend;
    end
end
```